# Unexpected negative value in Int32Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer

```
const x = new Int32Array(1);

x[0] = 699044815921;
console.log(x[0]);
-1034853327
```

Who can explain why there is a negetive number?

Comment: Because you aren't using an Unsigned Integer array

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow : *"If the variable has a signed integer type, a program may make the assumption that a variable always contains a positive value. An integer overflow can cause the value to wrap and become negative, which violates the program's assumption and may lead to unexpected behavior (for example, 8-bit integer addition of 127 + 1 results in −128, a two's complement of 128)."*

Comment: Try to use intval() to fix that.

Comment: Besides, that number would even be too large to be represented by a 32bit unsigned integer.

Comment: How the way solve it and store large integers? First in mind use a float64 to store

Comment: how about const x = []

Comment: do you need explanation or fix?

Comment: one way I feel is to use Float64Array to store values like this one? Maybe any others ways?

Comment: Simple JavaScript Number, the one you get with `let x = 10`, is a 64 bit float, which can safely store up to `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. If it is still not enough, there are bigint libraries for JS, though at this point you gotta ask yourself if JS is the right language to do whatever you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Int32Array allows 32 bits per value, with 32nd bit (from the right) being reserved to specify the sign of the number. The number you're trying to fit is `(699044815921).toString(2).length == 40` bits long, so 8 leftmost bits are discarded, 32nd bit is interpreted as a sign bit, and you get what you get as a result.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: For further study, you can use binary constants to see how sign bits affect the numbers: `let x = new Int8Array(1); x[0] = 0b00000001; console.log(x[0]); x[0] = 0b10000001; console.log('sign bit set', x[0]); x[0] = 0b111110000001; console.log('4 bits overflow', x[0]);`